# FileMaker Pro 13: Relationship between a text field and a container field

Tags: match, containers, relationship, filemaker

I'm new to Filemaker.
I want to create a database for my library.
Lets say we have a text field for the title of each book (book_title) and a container field for the cover photo (cover_photo).
I'd like to help me write a script that would allow me to copy the photo (that is, the content of "cover_photo") from one record to the other if the field "book_title" is identical within two records.
For example: lets say I have 5 copies of a book in my library. For the first copy I'll create a new record and I'll write the title in "book_title" field and I'll insert a photo in "cover_photo" field. But for the second/third/... copy I'd like to write only the title and, since it will match with the title of the first record, enter automatically the photo in the first "cover_photo" field without inserting it again.

I'd appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, it would be much better to use two tables, say Titles and Exemplars, with a one-to-many relationship between them. The cover photo would be stored in a field in Titles, and all the child exemplars could display it without you having to duplicate it.

This is assuming you have something unique to record about each exemplar - otherwise you could simply have a field for Quantity in the Titles table.